# GIT cloning branch stays with the name of the repository

Tags: git, branch, git-clone

I have one repository configured on GitLab with the name X and besides master I have another branch with the name of B21.0
When I run the following command on my local machine

```
git clone -b R21.0 --single-branch https://gitlab-hostname/Repos/wer/trt/X/X.git
```

The name of the folder on my local machine is "X" instead of R21.0 . If I run the command `git branch` it points me to the *R21.0 so I guess i am really cloning the correct branch but how do I do in order to the folder created name be R21.0 instead of "X" , the only way is to rename it manually ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt-ltdirectorygt

Comment: What @phd said. (Try putting the directory name at the end.)